# Why do I randomly get a "error to use section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'" when building an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have seen a few questions on SO about a similar error when deploying a website, but I seem to randomly get this error when **building** an ASP.NET MVC website in Visual Studio. Performing a clean usually fixes it, but is there any way to avoid this completely?

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. d:...\obj\debug\package\packagetmp\web.config

Note that it is complaining about the root `web.config`, not the one from the `Views` subdirectory.

Comment: Same problem being experienced here, I am using VS2010 RC1 on Windows 7 ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Comment: I experienced it on VS2010 Beta 2 and RC on Windows 7 with ASP.NET MVC 2

Comment: This is exactly the same in VS2010 Express - the released version, wasted ages of my time.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you're using the publish feature. I'm getting this error when using publish to a file directory.

Publishing your app creates a temporary copy of your application in the `\obj\debug\package\packagetmp\web.config` directory.

That web.config confuses the IDE which thinks it is an application, but its not in a virtual directory so you get the error.

**Workaround:**

It's a simple workaround to add this to a pre-build command:

```
 del "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config"
```

**Failed workarounds:**

- Changing the directory for 'Location where package will be created' under 'Package/Publish Web' settings doesn't seem to have an effect - even if you get clever and try to put it outside the project root with ......
- Creating an actual virtual directory in IIS for 'PackageTmp' didn't fix it either!

**CONNECT ISSUE:**

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503254/web-config-in-package-folder-makes-it-impossible-to-compile-debug

I hope they fix this in the RC!

Comment: It isn't fixed in the final build of Visual Studio 2010. I get this error, too.

Comment: I ran into this, and typical of Microsoft, closing the connect issue as "Not Reproducible". #fail

Comment: Updated non closed CONNECT ISSUE: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556312/

Comment: Once I added lines to remove the web.config for the transformation, it worked...
del "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config"
del "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config"
del "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\original\web.config"

Answer (score 9):

I was unable to get the other workaround to work, but the following pre-build event seemed to work for me:

```
rmdir /s /q "$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\Package"
rmdir /s /q "$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig"
rmdir /s /q "$(ProjectDir)obj\Release\Package"
rmdir /s /q "$(ProjectDir)obj\Release\TransformWebConfig"
```

Comment: Seems like overkill but it works for me, thanks! (VS2010 RTM, using publish)

Answer (score 2):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346680/210774) a similar question recently, and this looks like it might be related.

To summarize, I ran into this in one of our MVC projects, and it was due to having the `MvcBuildViews` property in the project file set to `true`. Setting the property to `false` fixed the problem.

```xml
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862996/210774) which outlines an alternative that does not require turning off view building.

Comment: I had this problem in Visual Studio 11 Beta. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can safely **put this target build at the end of your .csproj file** and leave `MvcBuildViews` to `true`.

It deletes the obj folder before starting the build...

```xml
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
  </Target>
```