# razor syntax with errors compiles when it should not compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors, razor, t4mvc

So I an into an error at runtime with my asp.net mvc3 app, when I checked the code I see that it has a red line on it, the **error list** says *there is no such function defined* but **it will still compile fine**. The error shows up only at runtime? I'm using **T4MVC** and I was hoping it would help me dodge problems like this!?

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

The code above should NOT compile because there is no such method there!

It fails at runtime :

[image]

This kinda of thing happens a lot, not just for un defined methods, but even variables, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is by design. The build of of MVC views is disabled by default. You can enable the build of your MVC views in Visual Studio like that:

- Right click on your project in Visual Studio
- **Unload project**
- **Edit project**
- Change the value for **`MvcBuildViews`** from false to **true**
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
  `<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`
  `...`
  `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`
  `...`
- **Reload project**

Next time you compile and there are errors in your MVC views, it will not compile.
The downside is, the compilation process will take longer.

**Update**

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-onl/2862996#2862996) on SO, explaining how to avoid the error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Comment: +1 yay! awesome! I knew there was a unknown feature somewhere, I just tracked down 2 more errors that would have bit me later!

Comment: +1, However when adding this it started complaining about this: `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS`

Comment: @Filip yes **I got that too**... try Cleaning the solution and building again, it may even mean you have errors in your views too like me!

Comment: @Filip Ekberg @giddy I updated my answer with a link to a SO answer, explaining how to avoid this error.

Comment: At first I thought great this is what i need. But then I got a whole lot of errors, from (i think) compiled views that shouldnt even exist anymore.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: If cleaning the solution is not enough, go and manually remove the folders in your projects obj-directory. Worked for me.