# ASP.NET MVC3 How to reference views directly from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

In my controller I want to specify a different View than default.
Like this :

```
public ActionResult EditSurvey(Int32 id)
    {

        Survey survey = _entities.Surveys.Single(s => s.Id == id);

        return View("Survey",survey);
    }
```

But instead of specifying the view as a string ("Survey") I would like to reference it directly, so if I decide to change the name of my view later on I don't have to change this string manually.

So I'm looking for something like this :

```
public ActionResult EditSurvey(Int32 id)
    {

        Survey survey = _entities.Surveys.Single(s => s.Id == id);

        return View(Views.Admin.Survey,survey);
    }
```

Comment: retagged if you don't mind, I think would be useful to people if the t4mvc tag is also part of your question.

Comment: FWIW having used T4MVC in a MVC2 application, I didn't find it offering any value. That it added ceremony to my coding that didn't actually materialize any added benefit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, there is no inbuilt support as the `View()` method expects a string, but there is a Nifty tool called [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC) created by [David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo) that does just that.

The documentation on codeplex has a manual install procedure, I would recommend getting it with NuGet package manager straight from VS2010.

Its pretty simple, the whole thing is files which you can just add to your project. (`T4MVC.tt` and `T4MVC.settings.t4`), everytime you change your code, **(1)** Right-click T4MVC.tt and **(2)** Click *"Run Custom Tool"*.

What it does is generate a class with Subclasses, Members, Properties for all your Controllers and Views. What it even does is create strong types for all your content, like images, css, js etc. (Which I think is just awesome)

Examples:
**This**

```
@Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm");
```

Would be:

```
@Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Dinners.Views.DinnerForm);
```

**This:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", "Delete", "Dinners", new { id = Model.DinnerID }, null)
```

Would Be this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", MVC.Dinners.Delete(Model.DinnerID))
```

**This :**

```
<img src="/Content/nerd.jpg" />
```

Would be this instead:

```
<img src="@Links.Content.nerd_jpg" />
```

You do have to Right-Click on the `tt` file and "Run Custom Tool" as mentioned before every time you change your views, controllers, however, if you want to automate this, [Check out Chirpy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/07/17/check-out-chirpy-a-very-cool-add-in-to-run-t4mvc-and-do-many-other-cool-things.aspx) which does that and more.

(**Note** T4MVC has aspx/mvc2 examples on the docs but works fine on MVC3 as I use in production with a MVC3/Razor app)

Also see [T4MVC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/t4mvc) on SO.

Comment: Great suggestion, but T4MVC doesn't support MVC3 and Razor yet. Or does it?

Comment: @fencliff It doesn't necessarily need to support mvc3 as such, since it just creates classes in the back, I currently use it in a production MVC3 application with Razor and it works a treat.

Comment: @giddy Neat! I looked into it when MVC3 RTM dropped a while back, and for some reason got an idea it wasn't compatible. Good to know!

Comment: @fencliff updated my answer with Razor syntax, looks so neat!! I've been using it since Mvc3 RC2, its mostly flawless! =P And really saves you a bite in the butt for the future. (Infact they should make it part of MVC) Also, David Ebbo is just genius, just check out some of the code!

Comment: Good suggestion, to bad you still have to manually edit the member name. It's an improvement though, since now errors are thrown if I change the viewname.

Comment: @ReetZweet What do you mean manually edit the name? Also, note, View Razor/aspx views are not compiled in MVC, see this on how to enabled view compilation :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014317/razor-syntax-with-errors-compiles-when-it-should-not-compile

Comment: @giddy My code now looks like this: return View(Views.Survey,survey);
If I change my viewname to SurveyNewName, I have to edit the code manually to : return View(Views.SurveyNewName,survey);

Comment: @ReetZweet ;) This is precisely what you needed from ur question right! It **think** you should be able to hit F2 and rename it with Visual Studio. Haven't tried it!

Comment: @giddy Well, I can rename the file (Survey > SurveyNewName) .. run the custom tool for T4MVC.tt .. now it throws errors on the old member names that don't exist anymore (Views.Survey), so those I have to manually edit. All in all its a decent solution to my problem.

Comment: @ReetZweet Ah, ok, to make life even easier, In visual studio keep your cursor on Survey, then press **F2**, type a new name, and all the names should be updated, since its code VS understands how to rename it.