# ASP.Net T4MVC file not updating itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I am wokring in ASP.Net MVC (.Net 4.0) with `T4MVC` template.

So far this file was getting updated with entries automatically whenever I used to add new files into my project (like controllers, views, etc.).

But for some reason, it has stopped updating itself. I have just added new folder into project with 3 `aspx` files and also related controllers and models. But still T4MVC does not show these things at all and the compiler gives errors for missing things.

Can anybody please help me figuring out the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: **(1)** What are these _missing things?_ can you post specific error details? **(2)** you maybe be confused with what T4MVC does, thats why I directed you to an earlier answer I wrote about `t4mvc`, it has nothing to do with models.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

T4MVC will not update itself.

You have to Right-Click the `.tt` files in your solution explorer and click *Run Custom Tool*.

When you do this, your solution will also compile.

T4MVC changes all your controller methods to virtual and writes overrides for them. So when you compile sometime, T4MVC will have a compile error, thats probably because you renamed or changed the signature of a method in your controller. Delete this method off from T4MVC and click *Run Custom Tool* to regenerate.

See this answer for details on T4MVC:
[ASP.NET MVC3 How to reference views directly from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105059/asp-net-mvc3-how-to-reference-views-directly-from-controller/5105095#5105095)

Comment: That's correct, though if you install Chirpy (http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) it can update T4MVC automatically.

Comment: hey! The man himself! =D =D Yep, gotta love the artwork and docs for chirpy. I've linked to a detailed answer I wrote a while back incase the OP needs instructions and such.

Comment: Still relevant as far as 2021, VS19, T4MVC 4.2.4

Answer (score 5):

> That's correct, though if you install Chirpy (chirpy.codeplex.com) it can update T4MVC automatically.

[AutoT4MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d820b76-9fc4-429f-a95f-e68ed7d3111a) is a nice little light weight option that does the auto-running of the custom tool.

It only does T4MVC though so if you use Chirpy for other stuff it may be worth keeping.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to autorun t4mvc check-out this Visual Studio pugin http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ . It has also very nice other features.