# Visual Studio 2012 - Breakpoints in Razor view files (".cshtml") not being loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012, razor

When setting a break point in a razor view (".cshtml") the circle which is normally red turns to a red hollow circle when the debugger is started. When hovering over the hollow circle it displays the following:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

It's only razor view files, with normal ".cs" files there are no problems.

There are a lot of other questions which have proposed solutions for the same "error" message as above but none has actually worked. What I have tried:

- Cleaning the solution
- Ensuring that in the properties -> Web window, under the "debugger" section that ASP.NET is checked
- Ensuring that in the properties -> Build window, that both Define DEBUG and TRACE are checked and in the output section of the same window, clicking the advanced button, the debug info is set to "Full"
- Rebuilding everything a million times.
- Using VS with administrator rights (I do that normally anyway)
- Restarting system
- Restarting site in IIS
- Ensuring that the Active Solution Configuration is set to Debug
- Checked that in the web.config file, compilation debug="true"

**Edit:** I'm referring to the razor code of course, not html or even javascript. E.g. setting a break point in a foreach loop in razor

**Edit2**: I'm able to step through the razor code if I set a breakpoint in a controller, as the the debugger will go through the view before being "done". I'm still not able to actually set breakpoints in razor view files though. The hollow circle is still showing and it won't get hit.

**Edit3**: Killing the "IIS Working Process" which points to w3wp.exe temporary solved the problem. I was able to debug razor views again. A few hours later, the same problem again.

Comment: You can't debug html in visual studio. Only programatical code will hit.

Comment: only razor code will be debuggable

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the razor code. It worked a few weeks ago, now it doesn't.

Comment: This suggests that the project is not being debugged and build when running the application

Comment: If it also happens on a newly created project, then you may need to reinstall Visual Studio. I had a similar problem, debugging cshtml never came back, and did not find another solution :(

Answer (score 3):

I found out that toggling the **Build Action = Content / Compile** (in the property window) on the `.cshtml` file (with a build in between) **let me set break points again**.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your looking for.

You need to compile your views at compile time not asp.net runtime.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052993/955831

Answer (score 0):

Remember that views are actually compiled when you request the page (by default).

This means when you set a breakpoint in a view:

1. It shows the "No Symbols" error. **This just means the view isn't
   compiled yet.**
2. It shows the breakpoint fine. **This just means
   that it found SOME compiled version of the page.** Like the LAST working version...

**So basically its not meaningful information to look at what it says when you mouseover the breakpoint in a view (at least in this regard)**

If you are trying to debug this page, then you **have a problem**. Look at what the debugger is outputting to your BROWSER instead and fix that first. I think we'll be surprised about how many people are going to facepalm at this.

Answer (score -3):

In your web.config file, check that debug="true" under .

Comment: Forgot to add that to the list of what I have tried. Sorry. Will update the list in the question