# Compile time check of .svc files

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm attempting to tidy up some project references and have broken the WCFs because the .svc files don't appear to be compiled.

We have the .svc in a separate host project to the code, e.g. Calculator.svc contains:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="demo.Services.CalculatorServices.CalculatorSvc" %>
```

And in another project, say "ProjectB", we have CalculatorSvc.cs.

I removed the reference to "ProjectB" from the host project, as the tool I was using said it's not being used, and as the solution compiled I was happy. Unfortunately, I was mistaken.

Is it possible to perform compile time checks for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is. ASPX, SVC and the like use [dynamic compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms366723(v=vs.100).aspx), which means they will get compiled at run-time / first request.

For ASP.NET MVC you have the same problem when compiling views, and there *is* [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052956/razor-views-are-not-giving-compile-time-error), but I've never seen something like that for services or ASP.NET pages.