# Precompiling asp.net application fails (web.config)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, precompile

I have tried compiling the application after build from inside visual studio when publishing, it always fails. The application builds fine if I do not try to precompile. I've also tried compiling it from the command line but it has not worked either.

The error message is more or less the same in both VS and command line, here's the command line error:
web.config(31): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allow Definition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

I have tried the usual solutions that I have found searching for this error:

-creating the application in IIS (this was already done, tried it again on a new folder, no difference)

-removing surplus web.config files, this made no difference.

-removing the obj folder, this made no difference either.

I am now wondering if it's because of what it says in web.config, line 31:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

However removing this is not making any difference either. I am compiling this application from a workstation that has VS2010 installed on it, it's meant to go on a W2k3 SBS webserver that's IIS 6.0 and the NET framework. I am not sure if that can cause this error, the command line command I am using looks like this:

```
aspnet_compiler -v /AppName -p "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AppName"  "\\WebServerName\Inetpub\wwwroot\AppNameFolder"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' error when publishing from VS2010 (but only after a previous build)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on)