# MVC3 Login using web.config, Error "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' "

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, forms-authentication

I'm creating a very simplistic MVC3 website. I need to add no database authenication.

I'm using a standard MVC project with the scaffolded account controller.

In the web.config file I have

```
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn">
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="admin" password="mypassword" />
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
```

I get the following error. (I'm using casinni, This error is usally because an Application hasnt been declared)

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been a massive numpty! I've been editing the wrong web.config file!

I edited the one under the /views folder when I should have edited the one under the root, doh!

Comment: This was MASSIVELY helpful to me. I never thought about there being another webconfig file, and boom--sure enough, that's the one I was editing, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try Build and clean the solution. I have to do it after I publish.  Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on)

Comment: Hi Graeme, cheers for your answer but I can't run it locally. I havent got to the publish stage yet.