# MVC3 ASP.NET It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, virtual

I have looked up solution, but I haven't quite found the right solution for this problem. I would use to just clean my VS and that would fix it, but now it continues to keep coming up. Thanks!

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'     beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being       configured as an application in IIS. C:\Users\atruong0\Documents\Visual Studio  2010\Projects\TubeRecord\TubeRecord\cathodeassembly\web.config

Comment: Which IIS version? 6, 7, 7.5? Or is it ASP.NET dev server launched by VS?

Comment: Its just running on VS2010, yeah the dev server launched by VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, So I figured out my simple problem. I just had another folder with duplicate files in it x_x. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem after enabling view compilation for my solution.  I tried lots and lots of solutions but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

The first thing you'll want to do is install the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) if you don't already have it.  That was supposed to fix the problem, but for me, at least with VS Web Developer Express 2010, it didn't help.

I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on) about it and there are a lot of possible solutions there.  I tried all of those before I found out about the tools update, but alas, no joy.  I'd definitely recommend trying the tools update before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yeah I already have VS 20120 Tools Update installed. x.x