# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'

Tags: web-config, visual-studio-2012, publish

I'm using visual studio 2012 when I try to publish my web application I get the following error:

```
Error   1   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\web.config    24  0   Pixelate
```

Here is the contents of the output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Pixelate, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" and "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
1>  Pixelate -> [...]\bin\TwistedPixel.Pixelate.dll
1>  '[...]\bin'
1>  CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
1>  UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
2>------ Publish started: Project: Pixelate, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Connecting to [...]...
2>Transformed Web.config using [...]\Web.Debug.config into E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Transformed[...]\Web.config using [...]\bin\Web.Debug.config into E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\bin\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -c -d E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir 
2>E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\web.config(24,0): Error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

If anyone can shed some light onto why this is happening and how to fix it, that would be great.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding (it rebuilds fine) I have tried deleting the bin, obj and have move the temp output directory - still the error persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' error when publishing from VS2010 (but only after a previous build)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on)

Answer (score 29):

This is a problem with an extra `web.config` being created by the Publish process.    Hover over the tab for the `web.config` and you'll see the extra file's location that you can then clean out.   Might even be for a different configuration but it still throws the error (e.g. Debug vs. Release)  Probably in something like `<app>\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\web.config`.

Delete it and you should be good to go.    Might recur on later publishes though.

Comment: This was amazingly helpful in finding the solution to the same problem I was having, in my case the web.config "Copy to output" property had been changed to "Always", by changing it back to "Do Not Copy", solved this. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be a pretty common issue and the error message is absolutely no help when this is caused by the extra web.config being created by the Web Publishing feature in Visual Studio.

I was able to overcome by forcing my ASP.NET application project to purge the obj directory after every build.

Add the following to your post-build event, and run the post-build event: 'Always'

```
rmdir /S /Q "$(ProjectDir)\obj"
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Release mode.

Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.

Build whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with one of the settings in your web.config. The error may give you an idea of the location.

Comment: Line 24 of web.config is the session state handling. For what little I understand of this issue it has to do with the fact that the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -c -d E:\Temp\BUILD\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir has created a copy of the web.config outside of an application which it does not like...

Comment: The web.config gets copied from the application directory to the bin directory which it does not like...

Comment: Nothing has changed in the web.config least of all that line. The line that it refers too is this:

<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="120" sqlConnectionString="PixelateApp" timeout="525600" cookieName="pixelateSessionId" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>

Comment: Well, I can't tell you the exact location of the error, but it is contained in your web.config. I suggest you add a basic one to see whether that error goes away and then start adding in your custom configuration until such point as you do get the error.

Comment: Also, do you have any folders with other web.config files in, or just the single root web.config

Comment: not available have other web.config files in another subfolder of root ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about the default namespace changing.
If you change the old, it will be fixed.

[image]