# ASP.NET Issues opening web application in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have never dealt with ASP.net and I received a folder from a classmate that I need to open up to see the content of the web application. I have tried everything but can't seem to get this application to load properly. I have asked an instructor at my school for assistance and he told me to make sure the instance is correct for SQL server on my computer and for the database to be loaded.

I have found the instance name for SQL server and have placed it in the location where it was originally my classmates instance under add name = "ConnectionString"connectionString="Data Source=(Minh-PC). As for the database I have loaded it up in SQL server under that instance. Am I doing this correctly?

Error messages in Microsoft Visual Studio.

**Warning 1 The 'targetFramework' attribute is not allowed. C:\Users\Minh\Desktop\PanderamaGaming (3)\PanderamaGaming\Web.config    40  20  C:...\PanderamaGaming (3)**

**Error 2   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\Users\Minh\Desktop\PanderamaGaming (3)\PanderamaGaming\Web.config    17**

Whenever I load it up it's going straight to a directory and I have an error whenever i try to load the pages.

Error when I try to load the website:

**Server Error in '/PanderamaGaming (3)' Application.**

**Configuration Error**

**Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.**

**Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.**

**Source Error:** 
   **`Line 15:   </connectionStrings>`** 
   **`Line 16:     <system.web>`** 
   **`Line 17:       <membership>`** 
   **`Line 18:         <providers>`**
   **`Line 19:           <clear/>`**

**Source File: C:\Users\Minh\Desktop\PanderamaGaming (3)\panderamagaming\web.config    Line: 17**

Please help me out. I've been struggling on this for over a week now.

Comment: Your terms are way too vague. In order to troubleshoot, you need to research the cause of the exact error you receive. "It's not working" and "I get an error" is not a proper starting point to do that, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was just thinking that when i was typing that as I was going to have 5 images attached but couldn't do so as I am new. Changing the wording with more examples.

Comment: Have you tried the answers in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970376/it-is-an-error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplicat

Comment: Acutally looking at your error, I am guessing it is because of your folder structure containing multiple web configs at different levels move your PanderamaGaming folder to a new area eg c:\test\PanderamaGaming and try opening it from there.